# Solve this inequality using a factor table

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: Use factor table to determine the intervals on which -3t(t+4)(t-2)^2 > 0

Now I made this table, and my problem is the last column. The product is positive in my answer (the red colored), but the true answer is negative. Can anybody tell me why am I wrong? 
[image]

Comment: Did you forget the factor of $-3$?

Comment: If I graph this inequality, all these intervals are true except the last one. The table is right.

Comment: I don't think so.  I'll provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table, it seems to me, should appear as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
& t < -4 & -4 < t < 0 & 0 < t < 2 & t > 2 \\
-3 & - & - & - & - \\
t & - & - & + & + \\
t+4 & - & + & + & + \\
(t-2)^2 & + & + & + & + \\
\text{product} & - & + & - & -
\end{array}
$$