# How can one go from $(x-5)^2 >9$ to $(x-5)>3$ and $(x-5)<-3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

How can one go from $(x-5)^2 >9$ to $(x-5)>3$ and $(x-5)<-3$ ? I don't understand what mathematical logic is used in this case.

Comment: I can work this out using a graph, but how, otherwise, does one make the jump?

Comment: Strictly speaking, one goes from $(x-5)^2 >9$ to $(x-5) > 3$ **or** $(x-5) < 3$.

Comment: Eyeball from, I don't believe so,  and I feel it has something to do with the fact that square rooting a 9 gives +/-3.

Comment: There should be a $-$ in front of the second 3. Unfortunately I can't edit that in. The point is that only one of the two statements can be true, so it is incorrect to use "and".

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$(x-5)^2-9>0\to [(x-5)-3][(x-5)+3]>0$$

so,

$1)$ $(x-5)-3>0$ and $(x-5)+3>0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(x-5)>3$ and $(x-5)>-3$.

Once both inequality have to happen at the same time we then should get the intersection, what give us

$$(x-5)>3$$

$2)$ $(x-5)-3<0$ and $(x-5)+3<0$

can you finish?

Comment: I'm working through it.

Comment: This is the only answer that is a real explanation. It's also exactly how I would explain it. +1 for you.

Comment: Dear Arnold, I would get contradicting answers. Plus, how do I figure our which way the inequality sign goes? Usually a graph is what I go with... oh wait, I'll try some sign analysis.

Comment: @Mathematician: I made a update solving the first part.

Comment: How can x-5 be more than -3 and 3 at the same time? How can they both be critical values?

Comment: May you use words in your explanation please? :) I apologise for taking up too much of your time.

Comment: @Mathematician: Once the expression is factorised, the easiest way of seeing where it's positive/negative is to make a table of where each factor is positive/negative, like in this answer, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1477218/1242

Comment: That's what I meant by 'sign analysis'. That's the easy method, i'm trying to understand what arnaldo did in his method.

Comment: @Mathematician: Fine, but why bother with the hard way when you can make it easy? ;-)

Comment: Because what do I learn if I just keep practicing a way that I know?

Comment: @Mathematician: the idea that I just wrote is what support the sign analysis. What I meant is if $a.b>0$ then both numbers have the same sign. It means that $a>0$ and $b>0$ or, in the other hand, $a<0$ and $b<0$.

Answer (score 1):

we use the square root non both sides and we get
$$|x-5|>3$$ and this is equivalent to
$$x-5>3$$ if $$x\geq 5$$
or
$$-x+5>3$$ if $$x<5$$

Comment: How does square rooting both sides give that the absolute value of x-5 is more than 3?

Comment: since $$\sqrt{(x-5)^2}>\sqrt{9}$$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $x^2 = k^2 \implies |x| = k$. As a consequence, if $x^2 \leq k^2$, then $|x| \leq k$. A similar inequality follows for the $\geq$ case.

Comment: You should recheck what you wrote

Comment: And now you should recheck it again

Comment: Sorry. I'm not feeling well so there are bound to be mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If $(x-5)^{2} > 9$, then $|x-5| > 3$; note that $\sqrt{\xi^{2}} = |\xi|$ for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that $|x-5| > 3$ if and only if $x-5 > 3$ or $x-5 < -3$.

Another way: If $-3 \leq x-5 \leq 3$, then $(x-5)^{2} \leq 9$; hence the statement must be true.